# moving window in R

Tags: r, xts

I am trying to add an extra column to an xts object in a moving window.
this is my original data

```
2010-09-08 15:02:00 9105 9115 9105  9115     20    
2010-09-08 15:04:00 9120 9120 9105  9120     77    
2010-09-08 15:08:00 9120 9125 9120  9125     86    
2010-09-08 15:11:00 9120 9120 9120  9120      7    
2010-09-08 15:14:00 9120 9125 9110  9125     43
```

I want to add a column at the end to get the following output:

```
2010-09-08 15:02:00 9105 9115 9105  9115     20     -1
2010-09-08 15:04:00 9120 9120 9105  9120     77     -2
2010-09-08 15:08:00 9120 9125 9120  9125     86     -3
2010-09-08 15:11:00 9120 9120 9120  9120      7     -4
2010-09-08 15:14:00 9120 9125 9110  9125     43      0
```

I have written the following code,

```
   x<-x[order(x[,1])]
   window<-nrow(x)
   k<-0

   for (i in 1:nrow(x)) {
   result<-cbind(x[i,],k) #tried result[i], but got an error
   k=-i
   } 
   return(result)
```

but it only returns the last row and that too with a column number -4 instead of 0

```
 2010-09-08 15:14:00 9120 9125 9110  9125     43      -4
```

Answer (score 2):

When we create a random data.frame with a few columns:

```
dat = data.frame(x = runif(5), y = runif(5), z = runif(5))
```

adding the desired column is quite easy:

```
dat$new = c(-1:-(nrow(dat) - 1), 0)
> dat
           x         y          z new
1 0.23164856 0.1244782 0.04444403  -1
2 0.02956714 0.1166311 0.68492965  -2
3 0.55612567 0.5486006 0.50465624  -3
4 0.98814715 0.2224405 0.26576011  -4
5 0.24729992 0.1294572 0.27477560   0
```

The important thing here is to think vectorized, there is no need for the for loop.

But maybe you could elaborate as to what you want to make this solution more general.

Comment: Paul, thanks for your response. I have a time series whose length varies depending on my choice of start and end date. hence in your above example, if I could replace -4 with an equivalent of -nrow(x), that would solve my problem.

Comment: @itcplpl: would that need to be `-nrow(x)+1`, since the last row is zero?

Comment: Edited my answer. If this solves your problem, could you mark it as the correct answer by ticking the tick mark? Shows people the question is solved en gets me some rep ;).